# DynamoDBへの反映の順番とタイトル行の削除について

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDBテーブルへの登録順番が
「0→1→2→5→3→4→6→11→10→8→7→9」
となります。
「emp_data」の後の数字の順番ではないのでしょうか？
また、CSVにはタイトル行が含まれておりますので、2行目から取得する場合、
どのようなコードを追加したらよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```py
import boto3
 
# S3、DynamoDBテーブルへの接続準備
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("test-jsonlog")
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    # S3情報をeventから取得
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
 
    # オブジェクト（CSVファイル）を取得して行ごとにデータを取得
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode("UTF-8")
    employees = data.split("\n")
 
    # 取得したデータの値を1つずつカンマで分けてテーブルに登録
    for emp in employees:
        print(emp)
        emp_data = emp.split(",")
 
        try:
            table.put_item(
                Item = {
                    "Agent"                       : emp_data[0],
                    "Agent Hierarchy Level Five"  : emp_data[1],
                    "Agent Hierarchy Level Four"  : emp_data[2],
                    "Agent Hierarchy Level Three" : emp_data[3],
                    "Agent Hierarchy Level Two"   : emp_data[4],
                    "Agent Hierarchy Level One"   : emp_data[5],
                    "Duration"                    : emp_data[6],
                    "Log out"                     : emp_data[7],
                    "Log in"                      : emp_data[8],
                    "Routing profile"             : emp_data[9],
                    "Last name"                   : emp_data[10],
                    "First name"                  : emp_data[11]
                }
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

先頭だけ捨てるなら単純に処理中の行数を数えて先頭ならif文で登録しないようにするだけでは。